# How to monitor remote system metrics with telegraf?

Tags: monitoring, grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I would appreciate some advice on how to architecture a stack of `telegraf + InfluxDB + Grafana` to monitor a set of machines.

#### My scenario

I have installed successfully the stack `telegraf + InfluxDB + Grafana` in a machine I will call "monitoring instance".

My system is an API consisting in one machines running nodejs and a postgres instance.

I can collect metrics from my Postgresql database (using the telegraf input plugin for postgres) and also my app (I'm exposing some metrics in prometheus format that telegraf pulls using the prometheus input plugin).

#### My questions and doubts

- What is the best way to monitor also the system metrics (cpu, mem, etc) of the node and postgres instances? Should I install a telegraf agent on this machines?
- How to send the local data to the "monitoring instance"?
- Should the local telegraf agents write directly to influxdb or should they send metrics to the telefraf installed in the "monitoring instance"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, first start with the Telegraf agent so that you learn how powerful and flexible it is, and then check out which plugins you can use. Telegraf can push data directly into InfluxDB, you may want to do that before starting to build anything complex. You specify the IP+port of InfluxDB in the Telegraf config file, and while you're at that, you'll see what else it has to offer. Kafka is a total overkill if you're just starting with this. Start small and easy and build your knowledge and understanding from there on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system/server metrics should be collected by a locally installed telegraf.

You can send the metrics from the system telegraf directly to the influxdb.  But, this makes the influx listeners susceptible to the amount of data pumped by local telegraf instances.  It doesn’t scale elegantly.

Instead, you could put a queue or Kafka in between the system telegraf instances and influx.  This will smoothen any unexpected load and should keep the influx listeners steady.  Between the queue/Kafka and influx, you can have a set of dedicated telegraf instances that load data from queue/Kafka into influx.  They could run as a Kafka consumer group and should scale easily.

System telegraf —> Kafka —> telegraf —> influx —> Grafana

Answer (score 2):

You should be able chain telegraf instances(monitored device -> monitoring device -> influx) using the generic socket writer output and the socket input plugin given that you configure it with the same data format.

https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/outputs/socket_writer
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/socket_listener
https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md

With telegrafs generic socket input supporting InfluxDB format you could also deploy fluent-bit on the monitored device instead of telegraf.
https://fluentbit.io/documentation/current/output/influxdb.html